# Render partials conditionally based if value exist in array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Use acts-as-taggable-on for tagging. Based previous questions in SO i read that i must minimize logic in the view and create a helper for conditions in the view template. Here's my code so far. (newby rails)

Routes:

```
resources :appartments do
  collection do
    get ':tag', to: 'appartments#index', as: :tag
    end
```

My controller:

```
def index
    if params[:tag]
            @apartments = Appartment.tagged_with(params[:tag])
            else
            @apartments = Appartment.all
            end
    end
```

Application helper:

```
def render_partials_conditionally
        if @apartments.include?("family")
            render :partial => 'familie'
            if @apartments.include?("groups")
            render :partial => 'groups'
        end
    end
end
```

The idea (i assume) is that i check if the value "familie" exist in the @apartments array with the include? method

Apartment index view

```
 = render_partials_conditionally
```

When i go to apartments/family the partial _family must showed, but nothing happens...no error, no partails

What am i doing wrong?

Grtz..remco

Comment: Did you try appending a partial to a string and returning the string instead? e.g.  `text = "" text << render(:partial => 'path/of/your/partial')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `Appartment` is a model, @apartments should be an array of objects, so `@apartments.include?("family")` and `@apartments.include?("groups")` will never be true.
Instead, the code could be like this:

```
@apartments.any? { |apartment| apartments.some_field == "groups" }
```

However I think it is still not good enough. A better approach could be that the helper only return the name of the partial, and then render the partial in view.

Comment: Thanks!

i do this in my console: 

b = Appartment.find(26) 
b.collection_list
  ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag Load (0.7ms)  SELECT `tags`.* FROM `tags` INNER JOIN `taggings` ON `tags`.`id` = `taggings`.`tag_id` WHERE `taggings`.`taggable_id` = 26 AND `taggings`.`taggable_type` = 'Appartment' AND (taggings.context = 'collections' AND taggings.tagger_id IS NULL)
=> ["lux", "familie", "dogs"]

but when i do this i my view nothing happens: 
- if @appartments.any? { |apartment| apartment.collection_list == "familie" }
%p familie content

Comment: So `collection_list` is an array, `include?` should be used: `apartment.collection_list.include?("familie")`. What do you mean by "nothing happens"? The partial was not rendered? Or no query was logged?